# Created branch in Visual Studio, want to push to my remote. getting error

Tags: github, visual-studio-2017, push, branch

I forked a project in github, then pulled it into my local VisualStudio.  in VS I have two remotes, the original and my fork.

I created a branch using Visual Studio locally. Coded, tested, committed locally.  Now, I want to push to my remote, but I get the error:

> Error encountered while pushing branch to the remote repository: Git
>   failed with a fatal error. unable to access
>   'https://github.com/xxx/xxx.git/': The requested
>   URL returned error: 403 Pushing to
>   https://github.com/xxx/xxx.git

but that is the *original* repos which I forked to work on.

How do I associate my local branch with *my* remote, not the original?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches)

> ```
> If you already have a local branch and want to set it to a remote branch you just pulled down, or want to change the upstream branch
> ```
>
> you’re tracking, you can use the -u or --set-upstream-to option to git
>   branch to explicitly set it at any time.

$ git branch -u origin/serverfix
Branch serverfix set up to track remote branch serverfix from origin.